# how can I insert a backslash in front of a forward slash in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

How can I convert HTTP:/example.com/RSFSR

I tried using `awk`, but it didn't work:

```
  read url
  awk '{gsub(///,"\/"; print}'
  echo $url
```

when it reaches `awk` it stops working.
expected result  `HTTP:\/\/example.com\/RSFSR`

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this?  People unnecessarily backslash forward slashes a whole lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed`:

```
echo "HTTP://example.com/RSFSR" | sed 's#/#\\/#g'
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` alone is used to escape the following character. To get a literal, `\`, you have to escape it and  say `\\`. The same applies to the pattern you express within `/ /`. In there you have to say `\/` to refer to a literal `/`.

All together:

```
awk '{gsub(/\//,"\\/"); print}'
#           ^    ^
#    escape /    escape \
```

See it in action:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\//,"\\/"); print}' <<< "HTTP://example.com/RSFSR"
HTTP:\/\/example.com\/RSFSR
```